# Probability to identify faulty machines.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There are four machines and it is known that exactly
>    two of them are faulty. They are tested, one by one,
>    in a random order till both the faulty machines are 
>   identified. Find the probability that exactly $3$ tests will
>   be required to identify the $2$ faulty machines.

$a.)\ \dfrac{1}{2} \\
b.)\ 1 \\
\color{green}{c.)\ \dfrac{1}{3}} \\
d.)\ \dfrac{2}{3} $

I did $\dbinom{3}{2} \times \dfrac{2}{4} \times \dfrac{1}{3}= \dfrac{1}{2} $

But the answer given is option $c.)$

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Answer (score 1):

The probability for faulty-not faulty-faulty is

$\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$

The probability for not faulty-faulty-faulty is

$\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$

The sum is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Note that faulty-faulty leads to only two tries.

Answer (score 1):

There are twenty four equally probable orders. (Six if you consider machines of the same type to be indistinct.)

You only have to test until either two non-faulty or two fault machines are identified, where upon you will know the identity of the rest of the machines.   This will take at least two and at most three tests.

- If two tests identify all the machines then the first two machines are both in the same category.   The probability of this is: $\underline\quad$
- Then the probability that three tests are required is: $1-\underline\quad = \underline\quad$

Comment: Of course, that means that the given answer is wrong.