# The probability that only two tests are required is

Tags: probability

Although it is the possible duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497541/probability-to-identify-faulty-machines?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa),but still i am posting this because I want to find flaw in my approach.

### Question

> There are four machines and it is known that exactly two of them are faulty. They are tested one by one in a random order till both the faulty machines are identified. The probability that only two tests are required is

### My Approach

Total possible outcomes =$$\binom{4}{2}=6$$

required outcomes =$$(\text{NF,NF,F,F)  and (F,F,NF,NF)}$$

> NF-:Not Faulty
>
> F-:Faulty

Using this $(\text{NF,NF,F,F)}$,we will be sure that last two are faulty

Using this $(\text{F,F,NF,NF)}$,we will be sure that first two are faulty

So reqd probability=$$\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$$

I know this is wrong, but please guide me where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Looks good to me.  You need two faulty in a row (probability $\frac 12\times \frac 13=\frac 16$) or two non-faulty in a row (same).  Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your response.Actually many are claiming answer to be $\frac{1}{6}$ https://gateoverflow.in/209735/isi-2017-21?show=209735#q209735

Comment: Well, maybe they are are overlooking the fact that getting two working machines in a row also solves the problem.

Comment: thanks .so my approach and answer is correct ?

Comment: I believe it is, yes.

Comment: @laura Yes, lulu is right, diabolic trap :)

Comment: And this means that your answer is correct.

Comment: You avoided the trap, well done!